# LibreOffice Calc / OpenOffice Calc / Excel: How to display a negative time duration?

Tags: excel, time, formatting, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I use a LibreOffice/OpenOffice spreadsheet to track my sleep.

Column A contains the time I fell asleep, and column B contains the time I woke up.

Column C contains an "adjustment"; if I woke up early, and then went back to sleep, I'll subtract the duration I was awake.  Similarly, if I take a nap, I'll add in the duration I napped.

Column D computes the duration of sleep: `=(B1-A1)+C1`

The trouble I'm having is visually representing column C effectively.  I want it to show "-1:15" if I woke up early, was awake for 1 hour and 15 minutes, and then went back to bed.  Conversely, I want it to show "+1:45" if I took a nap for an hour and 45 minutes.

How can I format column C to do this?  I've tried several custom formatting options, and none of my attempts have succeeded thus far.  Everything I have tried winds up displaying "22:45" instead of "-1:15".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [hack that you can use in Excel](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T006239_Displaying_Negative_Times.html)

Go into Options|Advanced|When calculating this workbook and tick 'Use 1904 date system'.

Then it will let you set the format to +hh:mm;-hh:mm and everything should work OK.

In Open Office it will let you use +hh:mm;-hh:mm

Answer (score 3):

in LibreOffice Calc you should format the cells as

```
[HH]:MM
```

to use negative times and hours.

Comment: Thanks.  Upvoted.  This appears to be the new default in LibreOffice when entering negative times (well, technically it's `[HH]:MM:SS`, but same idea).  So either someone at LO read this thread and improved the functionality, or others had the same issue.  This formatting works well for negative times (you get the minus sign before the hour), but is there a way to get a plus sign before the hour for positive times?

Comment: You may now also try `[BLUE][HH]:MM;[RED]-[HH]:MM` to get the different colors.